# Search through git revisions for method call

Tags: git, source-control-explorer

We have a function in our code which isn't being called, but should be. We know it was being called in a version of our software released about 2 years ago.

So at some point in the past few thousand revisions of our code (in a git repository), this function call was removed, and we need to know when this was.

Is there a way to automatically search through these revisions to find when that was, or will we need to do a manual binary search through the revisions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Git "pickaxe"](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitdiffcore.html#_diffcore_pickaxe_for_detecting_addition_deletion_of_specified_string):

```
git log -SYourFunctionName
```

This will show revisions where text containing `YourFunctionName` was either added or removed.